# Vote system with heterogeneous objects

Tags: mysql, sql, database

In simple words, how to design a voting system with heterogeneous objects that are voted.

For example I could have articles, movies, posts, comments etc., and I'd like all of them to be "voteable".

The question is how to design the database to keep performance and scalability at reasonable level?

**Some info/requirements:**

- only registered users can vote
- every single vote is stored in db for later statistic purposes (live using aggregated counters + verifying them sometimes)
- I'll add other voteable objects in future.
- voting restricted to one user can vote once per one object.
- there won't be cumulative rankings across multiple classes of objects.
- I will need to display the number of votes nearly always while displaying object, but it's not the most important to keep aggregated values always up to date, so cache will do it's work here probably. Only in some cases I will want to keep ii possibly up to date.

**My thoughts:**

For every table which contains voteable objects add a column `voteable_id` which could be unique across all voteable objects. The problem here is to keep this uniqueness. I'm working on MySQL where can't simple sequence like in, for example, PostgreSQL.

I could also keep `voteable_id` in a separate table which means, that in objects' tables I would be simple foreign key. Then I could also add some columns to let me configure that object in matter of voting like "block for voting" or keep aggregated counters in it.

What do you think? Could it work? Remember that this is only one of features, so it can't take all of resources. ;-)

Maybe any other ideas, or even better, verified solutions?

Comment: A limitation of SQL ... wouldn't it be nice if a table could be declared `IMPLEMENTS votable`?  Some questions:  Will you need to tabulate the highest vote-getter amongst all objects, or only within each class?  Will you need to display the number of votes whenever you display an object?  How stale can your current vote counts be?  Do you have to prevent registered users from voting more than once for an object or class of objects?

Comment: Yep, it's classic object oriented design case :D I added some info as answer to your questions

Comment: @OllieJones In PostGreSql, you can do that.

Comment: @downvoter any comment?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the polymorphic references idea used by Ruby on Rails.

Your votes table can have a 2-column foreign key - `votable_id` and `votable_type`. The `votable_id` is the key of the item voted on, and the `voteable_type` is an indicator to the table that item resides in - RoR uses strings, but you can also encode the type with an ENUM or a simple integer.

If you create a two-column index on those two columns(with `voteable_type` begin the first column in the index) you can make fast joins with whatever votable table you want.